# CORS issue while calling a post method odoo python and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, cors, odoo

i have added a file in nginx server /etc/var/www/html/test.html  .when on clicking a button in odoo python code it will go to this html page.It is used to get a value from the form on clicking the submit button, it will be passed as post request back to odoo..

But i am getting following error

*access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://209.23.104.2346:8021/update_value' from origin 'http://209.23.104.2346' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*

i have tried adding header Access-Control-Allow-Origin

used following code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Fetch Data</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align:center ;">
          <form action="/" id="searchForm">
            <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search..." />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#searchForm');


frm.submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://209.23.104.2346:8021/update_value",
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          },
        data: 'param1=122325',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success")
        },
        error: function (err) {
           console.log("error")
        }
    });

    });
</script>
</html>
```

How to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header needs to be added on the server-side rather than on the client side.

In other words, you need to add this header in your Nginx server by following one of the guides here: https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx

Comment: I have tried that,but still it's coming